# Camera Digit Prediction stopped working after moving to python 3.7, anyone know why?

Tags: tensorflow, opencv, gpu

When I moved my code from an interpreter based python 3.9 and tensorflow to python 3.7 and tensorflow-directml (so I could use my AMD GPU). The training part worked fine when I copied over the code. But when running the model I get an error suddenly complaining about the sizes of the input arrays to my neural network. The error does not occur with the initial interpreter but does with the second one even though the code is identical.
(The shapes of the digit array are the same for both versions (1, 28, 28) - binary image)

```
def cam_predict_digits(cam):
    dig = np.zeros((1, 28, 28))
    dig[0, :, :] = np.array(cam)
    digit = np.array(dig)
    print("predict input shape: " + str(digit.shape))
    # Make prediction
    prediction = model.predict(digit)
    print(prediction)
    print(f'Detected is probably:  {np.argmax(prediction)}')
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Z_Uni/Individual_Project/Python_Projects/NeuralNet_GPU/Conv_NN_GPU_Model.py", line 123, in <module>
    cam_predict_digits(Processed_Frame)
  File "C:/Z_Uni/Individual_Project/Python_Projects/NeuralNet_GPU/Conv_NN_GPU_Model.py", line 74, in cam_predict_digits
    prediction = model.predict(digit)
  File "C:\Z_Uni\Individual_Project\Python_Projects\NeuralNet_GPU\source\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 908, in predict
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  File "C:\Z_Uni\Individual_Project\Python_Projects\NeuralNet_GPU\source\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_arrays.py", line 716, in predict
    x, check_steps=True, steps_name='steps', steps=steps)
  File "C:\Z_Uni\Individual_Project\Python_Projects\NeuralNet_GPU\source\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 2471, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='input')
  File "C:\Z_Uni\Individual_Project\Python_Projects\NeuralNet_GPU\source\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_utils.py", line 563, in standardize_input_data
    'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 28, 28)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Could anyone explain why this is happening and what I can do to fix it? Thanks

Comment: no, it's not your python interpreter, your network input has the wrong shape

Comment: Ok but I use this exact input shape and it works with the original intrepreter